# How to resolve issue of help shortcut key (Cmd + Shift + /) not working?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I really like the shortcut key to bring up the help menu (`Cmd + Shift + /`). I use it navigate the menus by typing in short words.

However, I've just noticed that it's not currently working. Instead, I get an error noise whenever I press `cmd+shift+/`.

[image]

My first thoughts was that either another program is intercepting the shortcut in a global way. But I don't what that program might be.

- **How can diagnose the cause of this shortcut key failure (Cmd+Shift+/)?**
- **How can I resolve the problem?**

**UPDATE:**

- I tried changing the shortcut key in "keyboard shortcuts" to something else (e.g., `Cmd + Alt + Shift + /`). This alternate keyboard shortcut also triggers the error noise. So this suggests that the problem is not a conflict with another program.

Comment: Have you tried other shortcuts? Do they work? Have you tried hard resetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sameetandpotatoes made some great suggestions.

- I tried a different shortcut key for triggering the help menu and still had the problem.
- Restarting OSX resolved the problem.

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted (even though it won't fetch you any reputation points) so that others can ignore this question (or learn from it). :)

Comment: will do in a couple of days when self-accepting is permitted.